# is number between 2 values

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

What's the simplest way in actionscript to find if number is between -20 and +20, and return a true/false? I can see there's a number validator but I see it involves firing and catching events, which I think maybe overkill for the simple test I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way would be comparing the number with both values and logical combine the results:

```
return num > -20 && num < 20;
```

You may use `>=` or `<=` to include the values if needed.

You can make that into a nice function:

```
function isBetween(num:Number, lowerBound:Number, upperBound:Number):Boolean {
    return num > lowerBound && num < upperBound;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a function, conceptually like this:

```
protected function validatateNumbers(value:Number):Boolean{
if((value > -20) && (value <20)){
 return true;
}
 return false;
}
```

Then call the function whenever you want to validate your input.